# Sharing Online Content via LAN to another computer not connected to internet

Tags: php, html

I just started learning and want to know if it is possible for example
Computer A is connected to the internet and LAN
Computer B is connected to LAN, but can't connect to internet due to user privilege

Is it possible to embed online content on local webpage using Computer A as xampp server so that Computer B can open this online content?

Thank you

Comment: Why not just install a common proxy server?  No idea if it still works, but I used to use this back in the day:  http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/Network/proxy/Freeware.htm

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically speaking: Yes.

Possibility A) You have Computer A with any kind of installed Server (Node.js, Apache, Ruby, whatever...) on your lets say LAN-IP 192.168.0.100. So if this Computer grabs Content fron the Internet and puts it onto his Server this can be seen from any Computer in your LAN.

Possibility B) You write a small program to fetch the Content from the Internet and make a static Page out of that. If that Page is put in a shared Folder it can be viewed from any computer just by opening the shared file.

I'm sure there are tons of other possibilities as this is quite a common task for intranet-servers, meta-platforms or schools.